# Finding age in days from timestamp in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

Frankly I don't know Perl at all. I have to solve a problem using perl for some reasons. I tried searching for quick solutions and couldn't find any (my bad)

Problem: I have got a file that has list of file names and a timestamps (i.e. `2012-05-24T18:19:35.000Z`) in it.
I need to parse identify which of these are more that 90 days old.

I just need the check, everything else I think I have got in place already. When I googled some people suggested using some fancy datetime packages while some suggestions were around using of -M.

Quite confused actually. All help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That date format has the advantage that doing a lexicographical comparison between two of those string is (just about) the same as doing a date-time comparison. So you just need to get the date 90 days in the past into that format, and doing a string comparison.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
$_90_days_ago = strftime("%FT%T.000Z", gmtime( time-90*86400 ));

...
foreach $date (@your_list_of_dates) {
    if ($date lt $_90_days_ago) {
        print "$date was at least 90 days ago.\n";
    } else {
        print "$date is less than 90 days ago.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This could give the wrong answer near a dst change, cause not all days have 86400 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

This format is defined by both [RFC3339](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aRFC3339) (rather specifically) and [ISO8601](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aISO8601) (among many others).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DateTime                  qw( );
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339 qw( );

my $limit_dt = DateTime->now->subtract( days => 90 );

my $format = DateTime::Format::RFC3339->new();
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($timestamp, $filename) = split(' ', $_, 2);
   my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($timestamp);
   say($filename) if $dt < $limit_dt;
}
```

For example,

```
$ cat data
2012-05-24T18:19:35.000Z new
2012-02-25T18:19:35.000Z old
2012-02-24T18:19:35.000Z ancient

$ perl script.pl data
ancient
```

To ignore the time portion and just check if the date part is more than 90 days ago, use the following instead:

```
my $limit_dt = DateTime->today( time_zone => 'local' )->subtract( days => 90 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#! perl -w

use strict;
use Time::Local;

# 90 times 24 hours of 60 minutes, 60 seconds
my $ninety_days = 24 * 60 * 60 * 90;
my $now = time;

# parse the time stamps in the file
while (<INPUTFILE>)
{
    chomp();

    if (/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/)
    {
        my $year = $1;
        my $month = $2;
        my $day = $3;
        my $hour = $4;
        my $minute = $5;
        my $second = $6;

        # Looks like these are in GMT ("Z") so we'll use timegm
        my $time = timegm($second,$minute,$hour,$day,$month - 1,$year - 1900);

        if (($now - $time) > $ninety_days)
        {
            print "$_ is more than 90 days ago!
        }
    }
}
```

(that's just the basic - it needs the details about opening the data file, etc)

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look to this Perl module https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip

Comment: Without any explication, your assertion is useless.

Comment: It's big and slow and its interface is inconsistent. Anything that Date::Manip can do can be done more easily with DateTime and friends.